# Can we image the server without shutting it down?

Tags: fedora, physical-to-virtual

What is the method/application that can be used to image the server without bringing it down? I have to do server image but I can't turn it off during the process even for a second. The server is running on Fedora, and I'm planning to migrate everything to do virtualization.